# how to connect to CDH cluster from Remote python service

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, hadoop, cloudera-cdh, webhdfs

I have a CDH cluster running on aws . also have set of services running on different ec2 machines hooked to ECS cluster. all are in one VPN.
Use case that I have is to write data from my external service running on ec2 to CDH hadoop cluster. 
I am trying to find out the best way for it . please suggest me possible ways in python as how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Hadoop provides [WebHDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html), which is an HTTP interface into HDFS operations.  This allows you to manipulate files in HDFS using any Python HTTP client library such as [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#module-httplib), [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib) or [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#module-urllib2).  In fact, you can access WebHDFS using any programming language that provides an HTTP client library.

You could also use [Pydoop](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/), which provides a more direct integration between Python and HDFS.  The Pydoop implementation uses [LibHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html), which is a C wrapper over the standard HDFS Java client.  Thus, it would utilize the HDFS RPC protocol directly instead of HTTP.

Comment: Pydoop claims support for Kerberos.  In theory, any HTTP client library that can negotiate SPNEGO authentication would work, though I have to admit I haven't tried it myself with those Python modules.

Comment: thanks Chris for your valuable input. much appreciated